# Infinite number of intersections of a line with a plane

Tags: vectors

I am trying to understand the concept of an infinite number of intersections. Suppose that we have a line and a plane. We are trying to find any intersection by using the equation of the line in its parametric form. Then, we substitute the parametric equations in the cartesian equation of the plane. Then, the result would be 0 s = 0, SER. What does 0 s mean? "s" is a parameter by the way. I think I do not under the parameters well, so that is why I am stuck.

Comment: perhaps the line lies in the plane, so, for all values of the parameter, the corresponding point on the line is in the plane

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thank you. Sorry, I guess I do not understand what a parameter is in vectors. I have not found a definition that clicked with me. May you explain to me?

Comment: $0s=0$ means the zero vector times a scalar is still the zero vector.

Comment: for example, the $x$-axis is parametrized $s(1,0,0)$ with $s\in\mathbb R$.  The $xy$-plane is $z=0$.  For all $s$, the $z$-component of $(x,y,z)= s(1,0,0)=(s,0,0)$ is $z=0$.  Therefore, all points on the $x$-axis lie in the $xy$-plane

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I see! I think the parameter is sort of a way to multiply the direction vector to get all values of the line or plane. Is that fair to say?

Comment: I think so; for a plane, you'll have two parameters

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, oh right! Why are there two parameters anyway?

Comment: @CyclotomicField, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: If you have the line equation $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-5}{7}=\frac{z}{3}$ , then we say that the parametric form of any point on this line is $(2t+1,7t+5,3t)$ where $t$ is a parameter. What that means is that **for any real value of $t$ you put in, you will always get a point on that line, and the collection of all the points you get by putting all possible values of $t$ will be the line itself.**

Comment: @Aditya, wow, this is great, thank you. Parameters are making more sense now!